# css animation white-space: nowrap;

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I'm working on doing a css animation that would make text start at the right side of the screen, go to the left, the wrap back around and repeat.

I have some pretty large letters so I'm doing

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

so the text does not go down to another line.

I got the animation scrolling fine with

```
0% {
    transform: translateX(5%)
}
100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%)
}
```

and I put

```
animation: animation-name 5s infinite;
animation-timing-function: linear;
```

in the class

Only problem I have is that the with the big letters and the white-space: nowrap is causing the page width to increase in size because the letters are pushing the page width. Is there a way around this so that the animation will still scroll but not push the page width?

[image]

example picture above.

Comment: A marquee? Ehm... OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `overflow-x: hidden` in the class's parent.

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

div {
  font-size: 150px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: animation-name 5s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes animation-name {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(5%)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%)
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  Some pretty large letters
</div>
```

Comment: ya I did just that after posting. I feel dumb for asking but oh well lol